# Powershell ForEach replace (Bulk change primary SMTP in AD)

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I need switch the primary SMTP address in AD in bulk from users of an certain OU.

The challenge;

```
User1  
smtp:first.last@domain1.com  
smtp:flast@domain1.com  
SMTP:first.last@domain2.net  
smtp:flast@domain2.net
```

I need to make the first.last@domain1 the primary SMTP.

So far I have come to this;

```
$proxies = $null
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=users_test,OU=Test,DC=test,DC=local" -Properties name,mail,ProxyAddresses |
    Foreach {  
        $proxies = $_.ProxyAddresses | 
            ForEach-Object{
                $a = $_ -replace 'SMTP','smtp'
                if($a -match 'domain1.com'){
                    $a -replace 'smtp','SMTP'
                    Write-Host $a
                }else{
                    $a
                }
            }
        $_.ProxyAddresses = $proxies
        #Set-ADUser -instance $_
        Write-host $proxies
    }
```

The problem:

When I run the above script it obviously make both aliases with domain1.com the primary by replacing the smtp with SMTP on all that it finds matching the domain1.com.

Question: How can I make so it replaces only one?

I hope I explain myself good enough. Thank you in advance for any coming help

Comment: Which one (of the domain1.com addresses) should be the primary one? The one which is identical in the left part (before @) as the current one? One note: Don't use ```domain1.com``` for your regex match pattern. The ```.``` will match anything (it's a wildcard like ```*```). Use ```domain1\.com$```

Comment: @pwnosh -match is not regex (I think).

Which one of the domain1.com aliases doesn't matter as long as it only replace one. Right now the script is replacing all aliases with domain1.com. But ideally would be the first.last@domain1.com

Comment: @Heyvoon `-match` is regex ... take a look at the help [about_Comparison_Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1#matching-operators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not necessary to pick one particular domain1.com address, try this.

I've added a flag variable to set the primary address only once per user.
Furthermore I switched to the -like operator, as the -match operator isn't necessary and just produces more overhead if not used correctly.

And I've added the "start of string" regex character to your replacement parts (-replace also uses regex pattern)

```powershell
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=users_test,OU=Test,DC=test,DC=local' -Properties name, mail, ProxyAddresses |
    ForEach-Object {  
        # flag to avoid further processing after first match
        $userDone = $false
        
        $proxies = $_.ProxyAddresses | 
            ForEach-Object {
                $proxyAddress = $_ -replace '^SMTP', 'smtp'
                if (!$userDone -and $proxyAddress -like '*@domain1.com') {
                    $proxyAddress -replace '^smtp', 'SMTP'
                    
                    $userDone = $true
                } else {
                    $proxyAddress
                }
            }
            $_.ProxyAddresses = $proxies
            #Set-ADUser -instance $_
            Write-Host $proxies
        }
```

### Update 2021-01-13

Here's an update according to your request in the comments below.

> Could you show me how I could use the same script that would choose first.last@domain1.com. The ForEach should change to primary the one that has first.last.

Now regex makes more sense ;)

The code is untested against Active Directory, but should work.

The regex pattern in short:

```
(?i)             >case-insensitive match (=regex option)
^                >start of string
(?:              >non-capturing group (capturing is not required in your case)  
  smtp:          >starts with 'smtp:'
  [^\.\@]+       >matches any char at least once excluding '.' and '@'
  \.             >matches '.' once
  [^\.\@]+       >matches any char at least once excluding '.' and '@'
  @domain1\.com  >matches '@domain1.com'
)
$                >end of string
```

For more details please look at: https://regex101.com/r/atKdSw/1/

I've additionally added a warning when no match has been made due to whatever reason. The addresses are then not returned back to the source property (the addresses remain original).

```powershell
# pattern matches only addresses with format "*.*@domain.com" --> <anythingButDotOr(at)>.<anythingButDotOr(at)>@domain.com
$newPrimaryAddressMatchPattern = '(?i)^(?:smtp:[^\.\@]+\.[^\.\@]+@domain1\.com)$'

Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'OU=users_test,OU=Test,DC=test,DC=local' -Properties name, mail, ProxyAddresses |
    ForEach-Object {
        # flag to avoid further processing after first match
        $userDone = $false

        $proxies = $_.ProxyAddresses |
            ForEach-Object {
                $proxyAddress = $_ -replace '^SMTP', 'smtp'
                
                if (!$userDone -and $proxyAddress -match $newPrimaryAddressMatchPattern) {
                    $proxyAddress -replace '^smtp', 'SMTP'

                    $userDone = $true
                } else {
                    $proxyAddress
                }
            }

            if (!$userDone) {
                # if no address matched the pattern required for setting the new primary one
                Write-Warning "Unable to set new primary address for $($_.UserPrincipalName) | $($_.CanonicalName)!"

            } else {
                $_.ProxyAddresses = $proxies
            }

            #Set-ADUser -instance $_
            Write-Host $proxies
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much @pwnosh . This definitely does the job I wanted. Already taking advantage of your regex skills. Could you show me how I could use the same script that would choose first.last@domain1.com. The ForEach should change to primary the one that has first.last.

Comment: I've update my answer. Just check whether it works. As mentioned it's untested but should work ;)

Comment: THank you very much again . You're y hero! ;-)

Comment: I have modified the script to also set the new primary SMTP address as the "mailaddress" attribute.

New code can be found below;
https://gist.github.com/heyvoon/443aab886277b6975fc09c4b2a433da0

Comment: is there a way of not using concatenation (ForEach-Object |) and instead use a Foreach?